Amplify Credentials Expiring in 1 Hour (Despite 12-Hour Cognito Token)
I'm using Amplify Auth (Cognito) and Storage in my React application for file uploads. I've configured my Cognito user pool access token to last for 1 day. However, I'm encountering the "ExpiredToken" error when uploading a file that lasts more than one hour. if I log(Auth.currentCredentials()), the retrieved credentials show an expiration time of one hour as well even though the access token stored in local storage show an expiration time of one day.
Here's what I've tried:
Verified my Cognito user pool access token configuration to be set for 1 day.
Verified that the auth role in IAM has a max session duration is 12 hours
What I'm looking for:
How can I configure Amplify Storage to use credentials with a longer expiration time to align with my Cognito settings?
